# R - matching vectors to a table

Tags: r, vector, matching

I have a table with ranks:

```
Apple 1
Banana 2
Orange 3
... 40
```

where 1 is the highest, 40 is the lowest rank.

I am pulling out vectors from another source which contain anything from 1 to 4 entries, e.g.

```
c(apple,orange)
c(apple,banana,orange)
c(orange)
```

I want to match these vectors with a rank, so
c(orange) is easy, rank =3
but c(apple,banana,orange) should receive the lowest range from all of the values, so in this case 3.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
tab <- data.frame(
  fruit = c("apple","banana","orange"),
  rank  = 1:3
)

#   fruit rank
#1  apple    1
#2 banana    2
#3 orange    3

vec1 <- c("apple","orange")
vec2 <- c("apple","banana","orange")
vec3 <- c("orange")

tab$rank[max(match(vec1,tab$fruit))]
#[1] 3
tab$rank[max(match(vec2,tab$fruit))]
#[1] 3
tab$rank[max(match(vec3,tab$fruit))]
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, a nice simple solution, thank you for taking the time to put together such a clear example.

Comment: @user2813132 welcome to SO! Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if you think it is useful and/or satisfies the question posed.

Answer (score -1):

e.g.

```
# let tab = your table
x <- c(apple,banana,orange)
lowest.rank <- min(sapply(x, function(x) tab[names(tab)==x])
```